# How to set DateTime Formate like "dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm a" instead of "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" in android material design date time picker

Tags: android, android-datepicker

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.equals(mPickupDateTimeIcon)) {
            Calendar now1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            try {
                TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
                        GetBooking.this,
                        now1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                        now1.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false
                );
                tpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog");
                Log.d("Time", "Called");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                        GetBooking.this,
                        now1.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        now1.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        now1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                );
                dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
                Log.d("Date", "Called");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}}
@Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int dayOfMonth, int monthOfYear) {
        date = year + "-" + (++monthOfYear) + "-" + dayOfMonth;

        android.text.format.DateFormat df = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
        df.format("dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm a", new java.util.Date());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        String hourString = hourOfDay < 10 ? "0" + hourOfDay : "" + hourOfDay;
        String minuteString = minute < 10 ? "0" + minute : "" + minute;
        time = hourString + ":" + minuteString + ":" + "00";
        mMyDateTime.setText(date + " " + time);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if i got your question but if you want to change the way you get the date, just play with values and put then in the order you want, if you want ceros infront of the values < than 10 here is the code

```
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
      String month=String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1);
      String day=String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
      if(monthOfYear<10){
        month="0"+month;
      }
      if(dayOfMonth<10){
        day="0"+day;
      }
      String date=day+"-"+month+"-"+year;

   }
```